# Nextjs API endpoint on root

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a page on URL root, which is a Next page built with React.

And now I want to expose an API endpoint on root too.

```
`http://localhost:3000/` > points to React page
`http://localhost:3000/foo` > points to the Next API endpoint
`http://localhost:3000/bar` > points to the **same** Next API endpoint
`http://localhost:3000/anything` > points to the **same** Next API endpoint
```

Is it possible to rewrite the root path to an API endpoint? If yes, how?

Comment: You cant serve both api and a page on the same route. 
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction

Comment: @Disco I know, but I am not know how to write the proper configuration to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using rewrites in next.config
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites

Your folder structure should look something like this

```
 /pages
   index.js --> your home page
 /api
   [slug].js --> your api endpoint. Slug will be available as req.query.slug
```

Then in your next.config.js you should write the rewrites section like this

```
async rewrites() {
    return [
        {
            source: '/:slug',
            destination: '/api/:slug'
        }     
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correctly you are looking for dynamic route.

you can have

> http://localhost:3000/[slug]

So that,

```
http://localhost:3000 // will hit index.tsx
http://localhost:3000/foo // will hit pages/foo (because it's defined)
http://localhost:3000/bar // will hit pages/bar (because it's defined)
http://localhost:3000/{anything} // will hit [slug].tsx (because it's not defined)
```

but you can get the non matching routes in this case from the query params.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

// Component ...
  const router = useRouter()
  const {
    query: { slug }
  } = router
```

Your folder structure would look something like

```
/pages
 /foo
  index.tsx
 /bar
  index.tsx
 /[slug]
  index.tsx
 index.tsx
```

Comment: I want to route to the API, not to a page. Because I will only do a redirect based on the slug